# Show message and stop operation if data in sql becomes negative after operation

Tags: php, sql, database, negative-number

Here one can select up to five seats. But if there is only one seat available and user select five seats, the data in the database is stored as -4. I need to generate error message or alert if user is selecting more seats than available. How can I solve this problem?

```
<div class="row" id="form_book">
    <form role="form" class="from-inline">
        <label for="seats" class="col-md-4">Number of Seats: </label>
        <select name="selected_seat" id="" class="col-md-6 btn btn-default">
            <option value=1>One</option>
            <option value=2>Two</option>
            <option value=3>Three</option>
            <option value=4>Four</option>
            <option value=5>Five</option>
        </select>   
    <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Confirm Ticket" name="submit" id="confirm_ticket" />
  </form>
</div>


if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $seats=$_GET['selected_seat'];
    $id= $_SESSION['id'];
    $sql="select * from bus where id= $id ";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    /*---------other opreations ---------- */
    $new_seats= $row[7]-$seats;
    $sql_seat= "update bus set seats= $new_seats where id= $id";
    $query_seat=mysql_query($sql_seat);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?  I mean, fetch the number of seats that is left and compare it to the number of seats that the user has selected, if there's not enough seats show an' message. If you are all ready checking the number of seats available versus seats selected you shouldn't have a hard time figuring the `if(){}` logic behind it out.

Comment: Yep, it worked..Thanks for the tips..

Answer (score 0):

simple comparison will solve your problem i guess

```
/*---------other opreations ---------- */
if($row[7] >= $seats ){ 
  $new_seats= $row[7]-$seats;
 .....
}
else {
  echo "only ".$row[7]." seats are available";
}
```